# how to invoke a service's android method since void onclick function?

Tags: android

hello I'm trying to invoke a service's android method since a public void onclick and i have one mistake, it tell that i need insert "AssignemetOperator Expression" to complete the expresion, but i don't see where it's the mistake.
i put de code here 
the mistake is on the  boolean ret=bindService(.........
it´s inside of public void onClick
idcamarero was created how a global variable
thanks

View.OnClickListener buttonhandler=new View.OnClickListener() {

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText id_camarero = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.id_camarero);
        String numero = id_camarero.getText().toString();
        idcamarero=Integer.parseInt(numero);
        //Register the actions we want to receive via broadcast
        //MyService.LocalBinder.
     boolean ret= bindService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class), androidServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);          
         IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(MyService.DATA_RECEIVED_INTENT);
         registerReceiver(androidListener, filter);
     if((numero.trim().equals(""))||(existe==false)){
         AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

                // set title
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Fallo de id");

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                    //.setMessage("Click salir para finalizarprograma")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Salir",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            // if this button is clicked, close
                            // current activity
                            MainActivity.this.finish();
                        }
                      })
                    .setNegativeButton("Reintentar",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            // if this button is clicked, just close
                            // the dialog box and do nothing
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

                    // create alert dialog
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                    // show it
                    alertDialog.show();
                }

     else{
    // Intent intent= new Intent(GestorRestauranteActivity.this,MenuMesas.class);
    // intent.putExtra("id", numero);//enviamos el id de camarero a la actividad que invocamos
    // startActivity(intent);
     finish();
     }
    }

};
```

Comment: At which line do you get this error?

Comment: the mistake is on line 7th when I do the bindService

Comment: Where is `androidServiceConnection` defined? You pass that as a parameter in the bindService() call.

Answer (score 0):

The 5th line of your code:

```
idcamarero=Integer.parseInt(numero);
```

won't parse because you haven't declared the type of the variable `idcamarero`. Either you need to prefix the line with `int` or just remove it entirely (it doesn't look like you need this).